# Preselect object in select-input

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a form with a select input field which is based on objects:

```
<!--
this.options = [
  { name: 'Option A', id: 1 },
  { name: 'Option B', id: 2 },
  { name: 'Option C', id: 3 },
];
-->

<form #optionForm="ngForm">
  <select [(ngModel)]="model.option" name="option">
    <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option">
      {{option.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Initially, my model is set to one of these options e.g.:

```
this.model = { option: { name: 'Option B', id: 2 } };
```

How can I preselect this object in my select input? The whole model.option object should be selected.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/8gBUQrUNFOJQq7R7B1Gz?p=preview) with example component in `src/app.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the changes here https://plnkr.co/edit/YTMZ05Awd1AGDpds6QSO?p=preview.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model.option.id" name="option">
        <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option.id">
          {{option.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

Essentially you were storing the object in the ngValue rather than a property (in your case id/name). Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: With `[ngValue]` you can remove `.id` in `[(ngModel)]="..."` and `[ngValeu]="..."` and the whole `model.option` value gets replaced instead of just the `id` property`

Comment: This only changes the id. I want the whole { name, id } object to be selected.

Comment: @fwind have you tried what I explain in my comment above?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer isn't this just my example from the question? This binds the whole `model.option` object, but does not work with preselecting one.

Comment: The problem is you are trying to bind the same "object" to your ngModel. However, they don't have the same object ref in the template. model.option != option. `this.model` needs to have the same object ref of your desired object.

Comment: I see. Just assign the item from `options` to `model.options` that you want to have preselected. Assigning `{name: 'Option B', id: 2 }` won't work though because it's a different object instance. You need to pick one from `options` like `this.model.options = this.options[1];`

Comment: I guess I can add some logic to the constructor to match the selection that I have in my model. I thought that there would be a simpler way e.g. by setting a custom comparator.